# Mount Namespace: Normalize file path to init/root mount namespace

Tags: linux-kernel

I looked for various sources of information regarding mount namespaces in the Linux kernel and I have to say that I couldn't find much information on how it works underneath the hood (layout of structures and how they are all interrelated).

What I'd like to do is take a given path in process X's mount namespace and get the same file path in the init/root process namespace.

Example:

```
block device A has a file as blah/whatever/fileX

In the init/root process mount namespace, this bdev A is mounted on folder /root making the path /root/blah/whatever/fileX

In the process X mount namespace, this bdev A is mounted on folder /myfolder making the path /myfolder/blah/whatever/fileX
```

When a specific system call using the pathname into the kernel is made from process X's world, I'd like to take the pathname /myfolder/blah/whatever/fileX and convert it as it would be in init/root's world making the pathname /root/blah/whatever/fileX (or NULL if the file is not accessible through any mount point of init/root)

Some related question:
[Linux - understanding the mount namespace & clone CLONE_NEWNS flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889241/linux-understanding-the-mount-namespace-clone-clone-newns-flag)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are not exactly looking for mount namespace but just a option which is called bind mount in mount system call or cli.

For root/init the device is mounted in blah/whatever/fileX ... you can bind mount the same blah/whatever in /myfolder/blah ... thus the same fileX and same dirs are visible with two paths..

now unless you look for isolation i.e. you do not want any other process to look for these mount points, you can go and use mount namespace. The simplest what of doing this is starting processX using "unshare"