# rmdir failed because of "Device or resource busy"

Tags: linux, filesystems

there are a lot of similar problem like "Device or resource busy". But I think my problem is different with them.

I use mount --bind to bind a directory

```
mount --bind /tmp/origin /tmp/mount
```

and then could umount successfully

```
umount /tmp/mount
```

And then if I call rm at once

```
rm -rf /tmp/mount
```

I could get a error `Device or resource busy`. If I wait 2~3 seconds, and then call rm, it could success.

So this behaviour is very strange here. I try use

```
lsof +D /tmp/mount
```

could not see anything.

I also use `fuser -vm /tmp/mount`, could not see any process hold this folder.

I compare the `/proc/mounts` before `umount /tmp/mount` and after `umount /tmp/mount`. `/tmp/mount` has already removed.

I compare the `stat /proc/mounts` before `umount /tmp/mount` and after `umount /tmp/mount`. The inode also different, this means `/tmp/mount` has already removed complete.

Even I call `sync && echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and try to drop file caches, it still not work.

I try this in both Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 6.6. They have same results.

Comment: That's a great question. I'd give it an upvote but it's more a general computing question than it is programming-related so it’s *off-topic* for StackOverflow. It would be much more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or even [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thank you. How to move this to that? @AnthonyGeoghegan

Comment: No problem. If I was you, I'd copy and paste the content of this question into the new one and then delete this version to avoid the new question being flagged as a cross-post. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Because the above commands are happends in code, not from shell. The the reason of this problem is related to this params when call clone a process: CLONE_NEWNS. So I still keep it here.

Comment: That makes sense. BTW, I upvoted g-v’s answer as it provided useful relevant information. Even though your particular problem was caused by a different issue, I’d suggest upvoting their answer if it helped you debug your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Go it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for @g-v answer. But I found the result is another problem. We use CLONE_NEWNS flag when fork a process. More details could be found in [CLONE_NEWNS flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889241/linux-understanding-the-mount-namespace-clone-clone-newns-flag) and [MESOS-3349 Device busy bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3349?focusedCommentId=14738557&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14738557)

In a short word, we mount in parent process. And then umount in child process, because of CLONE_NEWNS, the mount point still exists which handled by parent process. So when call rmdir would got EBUSY error code.

To avoid above problems, we could use shared mount or slave mount. More details could be found in [LWN 159092](https://lwn.net/Articles/159092/)

Answer (score 12):

I faced problem like this because I mount shared folder in VM and I want to remove directory after unmount and I just want to share my solution.

1. un-mount path

   ```
   sudo umount /your_path
   ```
2. remove mout path in /etc/fstab

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```
3. reboot

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
4. remove directory

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /your_path
   ```

Comment: Actually he could remove the directory 3 seconds later, without rebooting, but thank you anyway for your answer, that could help someone else.

Comment: `umount /path -l` forces unmount

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the following operations are asynchronous on Linux:

- Closing file. Immediately after `close()` returns, `umount()` may return `EBUSY` while it performs asynchronous release. See discussion here: [page 1](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/fuse-devel/thread/CA+55aFyALiUbRVcxGGG79N-97pa997v9En64O9jLLBvBAO6vrA@mail.gmail.com/?page=0), [page 2](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/fuse-devel/thread/CA+55aFyALiUbRVcxGGG79N-97pa997v9En64O9jLLBvBAO6vrA@mail.gmail.com/?page=1).
- Umounting filesystem. Mounted device may be busy until all data is written to disk.

> Even I call `sync && echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and try to drop file caches, it still not work.

See [`sync(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sync):

> On Linux, `sync` is only guaranteed to schedule the dirty blocks for writing; it can actually take a short time before all the blocks are finally written. The `reboot(8)` and `halt(8)` commands take this into account by sleeping for a few seconds after calling `sync(2)`.

As for `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty objects.

Thus, immediately after your command, data may be still queued for write and umounting is not yet finished.

---

**Update**

However, when asynchronous umounting is in action, kernel will return `EBUSY` for operations on *mounted device*, but not for *mount point*.

So the cases above **could not** be the reason of your problem :P

---

**PS.**

Actually I don't understand why the man page states that `sync(8)` is not synchronous in Linux. It calls [`sync(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) which states:

> According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), `sync()` schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is done. However, since version 1.3.20 **Linux does actually wait.** (This still does not guarantee data integrity: modern disks have large caches.)

Comment: Thank you, let me try dig more details about this.

Comment: Nice ideas but none of them solve the issue on my end. 
looks like a flaw in the mount implementation

Answer (score -1):

- check

  ```
  df -h
  ```
- then

  ```
  sudo umount /path
  ```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps:

1. open Resource Monitor
2. click on "associated handles" drop box
3. search the folder creating problem
4. Right click on each process and "End process".

Now you can delete the folder